# establish passwordless login without asking the user

Tags: linux, ssh, password-management

On Linux when using dsa keys I establish passwordless login with the command

```
ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_dsa.pub user@target.host
```

This prompts the user for user's password on target.host. My script knows the password and the user shall not be bothered, how can I do this?

Comment: Create keypairs for each user and give the user the public key. This has been around for quite a while.

Comment: If you must do this, then you probably would want to look at using the `expect` based examples from the linked questions, to provide the passwrd.

Comment: Wait, you are using a key pair and _still_ being prompted for a password? Are you sure it's not the _key passphrase_ what it's being requested?

Answer (score -1):

Just generate a pair of keys and provide it with your script. This would be the preshared key to upload a real key.

EDIT:
Generate a separate keys for keydeployment: (deploy, deploy.pub), ship them with your script. This mean that from machine with script (so with those keys) you just can login without a password:

```
ssh -i ./deploy.pub user@target.host
```

Then use this key to deploy *user* key on the target:

```
cat deploy.pub .ssh/id_dsa.pub > both.pub
ssh-copy-id -i ./both.pub user@target.host
```

Comment: What the what? Give an example, please, as it's not at all clear what you mean by this.

Comment: You add a known private key to your software with whole purpose and restriction of uploading a new public key to the user. With this you don't need a password for the ssh-copy-id.

Comment: I assume you would have some kind of restrictions in place to prevent users from using this **shared** key from being abused?  Please elaborate.  What would prevent the user from simply using the *private* key you are suggesting that you would provide.

Comment: The same that would prevent the user from using *shared* password..